# block most traffic on an expensive link

Tags: iptables

I'm running with two wan links. The new one is expensive, and I only want to use it for ssh. The new link is on eth1, 192.168.8.1.

I am attempting to use ip tables to block all incoming and out going connections, except for ssh and except for traffic to 192.168.8.1.

Whenever I apply my iprules, I can no longer connect to my router, and I stop receiving ssh connections. I must have an error in my rules somewhere. Can someone help me find it?

```
# Prevent all traffic on eth1
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j DROP

# But make an exception for incoming SSH
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# ...and an exception for outgoing SSH
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# ...and an exception for any communication with the router
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -d 192.168.8.1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -d 192.168.8.1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Slight clarification needed by "New" link, is this the expensive one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `iptables` uses "first match" criteria. Reorder your rules so that the exceptions come first.

Comment: Agreed -[From the firewall Wizards](http://seclists.org/firewall-wizards/2002/Aug/20)